# Making table full width of email container on mobile

Tags: email, email-template, table, content-builder

I am creating a responsive email with SFMC content builder. I want to place a button in the center of the email with a white background. The template content background color is purple and I have made the button background color white within the block settings for the button. It displays fine on desktop (https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0vXA.png) however when viewing the email on mobile it reverts to this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPskt.png) where the template content background color is visible.

The table for the button doesn't seem to be expanding to the full width of the container. I have tried testing a full width table using just the html widget but the same thing occurs. I think it must be something that SFMC adds when using the content builder. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

What type of template are you using? Is it your own or one of the default templates? Since you've changed the button block background color to white I'd expect it to remain white. I did that using one of the Basic templates and it worked fine.